# Apache Solr Failover Support in Master-Slave Setup with multi data center

Tags: solr, scalability, failover

I am using Solr 6 for master slave set up. My issue is we do not have a auto fail-over in case master goes down. Only way is to manually change config of slave and make it master.

I read about using a load balancer for master level and using a  repeater.
In this approach is see following issue :

1. Slave will be syncing from one master at one time but both master could be out of sync at any given time for small time and it can impact Slaves as one time they read form most updated master and next they read form a repeater which was behind.
2. Application will also face same behavior while indexing.

Can anyone help me with correct approach for it. Also my use case is not fit for Sharding so i need to use master slave only.

Thanks
Viren

Comment: This is what SolrCloud was created for, it even has alpha features to allow [metadata about racks/datacenters/etc. and rules](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Rule-based+Replica+Placement). Since you no longer think in index version, but document version, multiple replications paths can be allowed for each document.

Comment: @MatsLindh is it related to shard distribution. I am using Mater Slave and Shard use case does not fit for me. So could you please explain ita little more if possible.

Comment: There is no need to shard a collection across multiple nodes unless you want to - use a high replication factor and `numShards=1` when creating the collection in cloud mode. You'll have to actually expand your question why this won't solve your problem, I can't really answer any issues you'd have if I don't know what those issues are.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for input. Actually we tried same thing but we saw unusual behavior. Write performance went down by using 1 shard. A simple index command was taking more than 30 second. But when it was moved to master slave same index request took 30 milliseconds. I could not find any issue in logs also.